# SwiftUI - How to display a custom banner notification in iOS 15.0 and above?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I created a custom banner notification using the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showAlert {
                VStack {
                    NotificationView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .animation(.easeInOut)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
            }
            Button("Show Alert") {
                showAlert.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output would be as below:

[image: Custom Notification Banner Example]

But when I run the same code under iOS 15.0 and above, I get a warning message.

> 'animation' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use withAnimation or
> animation(_:value:) instead.

To fix it, I used the code `.animation(.easeInOut, value: showAlert)` instead of `.animation(.easeInOut)` as **value** parameter is now required. After adding it, the animation stopped working.

Later I figured out to use **withAnimation {}** code in the "Show Alert" button like this

```
Button("Show Alert") {
    withAnimation {
        showAlert.toggle()
    }
}
```

This change would make it animate again, but it is not like before. It would animate the "NotificationView" only from 'bottom to top'. I need to animate it from both 'top to bottom' as well as 'bottom to top' like I did before.

How can I bring back the same animation in iOS 15.0 and above using the updated `animation(_:value:)` code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand from your question, to animate from top to bottom, you need to add alignment `.top` to the ZStack and add a button to the VStack with a conditional logic outside of it.

You can follow below code to get the desired output.

**Code:**

```swift
struct CustomScreen: View {

  @State private var showView: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {

      VStack {
        Spacer()
        Button("Show Alert") {
          withAnimation { showView.toggle() }
        }
        Spacer()
      }

      if showView {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
          .fill(Color.blue)
          .frame(
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1
          )
          .transition(.asymmetric(
            insertion: .move(edge: .top),
            removal: .move(edge: .top)
          ))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me the iOS version in which this code was tested? I tried it in iOS 16.2 but it is still showing the same old behaviour. Also, how did you reduce the animation speed? I couldn't find it in the code.

Comment: i'm testing in iOS 16.0 and run perfectly as shown in image and can you update your latest code in question?

Comment: Actually it works now. The key is to add `withAnimation { showView.toggle() }` which made the difference.

Comment: Great!..........  if it works for you then you can accept and upvote my answer so that it  will be helpful for others also.